# MSBuild warning messages in VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am getting many of the following warning messages. Is this something I should be concerned with?

> Warning   1   The element 'PropertyGroup' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid
>   child element 'ImportByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets' in
>   namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'. List
>   of possible elements expected: 'Property, AllowUnsafeBlocks,
>   AppConfigForCompiler, ApplicationIcon, ApplicationRevision,
>   ApplicationVersion, AppDesignerFolder, AspNetConfiguration,
>   AssemblyKeyContainerName, AssemblyKeyProviderName, AssemblyName,
>   AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile, AssemblyOriginatorKeyFileType,
>   AssemblyOriginatorKeyMode, AssemblyType, AutorunEnabled, BaseAddress,
>   BootstrapperComponentsLocation, BootstrapperComponentsUrl,
>   BootstrapperEnabled, CharacterSet, CheckForOverflowUnderflow,
>   CLRSupport, CodePage, Configuration, ConfigurationName,
>   ConfigurationOverrideFile, CreateDesktopShortcut,
>   CreateWebPageOnPublish, CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents,
>   DebugSecurityZoneURL, DebugSymbols, DebugType, DefaultClientScript,
>   DefaultHTMLPageLayout, DefaultTargetSchema, DefineConstants,
>   DefineDebug, DefineTrace, DelaySign, DisableLangXtns,
>   DisallowUrlActivation, CodeAnalysisAdditionalOptions,
>   CodeAnalysisApplyLogFileXsl, CodeAnalysisConsoleXsl,
>   CodeAnalysisCulture, CodeAnalysisFailOnMissingRules,
>   CodeAnalysisForceOutput,
>   CodeAnalysisGenerateS.... C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets  20  9   Miscellaneous
>   Files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ignore this warning, [see this link](http://sstjean.blogspot.com/2007/04/visual-studio-warning-element-in.html) for an explanation:

> When you apply the schema attribute to your Project element, Visual
>   Studio reads in the schema and uses the information indide to provide
>   Intellisense during your editing.  As an offshoot of this, it also
>   warns you when it finds that you have used elements or attributes that
>   are not part of the schema.  The custom property and item elements are
>   not part of the MSBuild schema.

Comment: Is there anyway to disable it, rather than just ignoring it?